# convert regular a tag to routerlink

Tags: angular, routerlink

I have HTML in a string coming from the server:

```
str = '<div>The linkL <a href="/en/about">About</a></div>';
```

This is just an example, I have a really long HTML with a lot of links.

in the template I have this

```
 <div innerHTML="str"></div>
```

Everything works fine, except that when someone clicks on the link the entire page reloaded, I need routerLink to replace all the `<a` tags.

Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: This isn't really possible unless you load the component using Dynamic Component Loader. Just using `innerHTML` won't compile the html and will render it as is. So even if you replace the `href`s as `routerLink` it won't really work. Are there links routes to the application itself?

Comment: you can use `router.navigate` to navigate to those routes in the click event of the hyperlinks

Answer (score 2):

Its not the `<a>` tag that makes the page reload, its the `href` attribute in it. Replace `href` with `routerLink` like this:

```
<a routerLink="/en/about">About</a>
```

To get that from the string, you can use: `str.replace("href", "routerLink");`

Comment: Thanks. But this is not possible. InnerHTML makes the content HTML